# Slice audio with ffmpeg with high precision

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I want to slice an audio file of 2.790703 seconds in **four equal parts** with `ffmpeg`. To get the total duration I run:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 dl.wav
```

If I divide `2.790703` by 4, the result is: `0.69767575`. Then if I try to cut from `0` to `0.69767575`:

```
ffmpeg -i dl.wav -acodec copy -ss 0.0 -t 0.69767575 -y dltest.wav
```

Then I get the duration (it should be `0.69767575`) I get `0.719819`:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 dltest.wav
```

Why is this inaccurate? Can I have a slice of `0.69767575` instead of `0.719819`?

Comment: Have you tried it without `-c copy`? Since wav file contains a raw samples you won't lose any quantifiable processing time. The copy operation maybe performed in blocks thus the inaccuracy. I can play with it later myself to verify this.

Comment: @kesh You are right! This was the culprit! Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I will accept it!